# How to not display the default template in one of the routes in Meteor Iron-Router?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to render my `home` template without the default `layoutTemplate`.
Iron-router Guide shows I need to use `Router.onBeforeAction`. I just can't figure out how exactly to implement it.

```
Router.configure({
 layoutTemplate: 'navbar'

}

Router.route('/', {name: 'home'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the default layout template by calling [`this.layout();`](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#layouts) in your route. Either you supply a different layout template, e.g. `this.layout('homeLayout');` or you just leave the arguments empty.

For example:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
    this.layout();
    this.render('home');
}, {name: 'home'});
```